# Return top 'X' records within multiple groups in one query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a list of records across multiple months i.e. September, October, November etc. and I need to return the top 10 results by count for each month within the same query. I have the below so far:

```
SELECT [Financial Year] & "Resolved" & [Text Month] & [SegmentDescriptionST] AS [Key], "FY" & IIf(Month([MinOfResolvedDate])<10,Year([MinOfResolvedDate]),Year([MinOfResolvedDate])+1) AS [Financial Year], "Resolved" AS Metric, Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") AS [Resolved Month], Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm") AS [Text Month], Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST, Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) AS Amount

FROM Content_Accuracy_q

WHERE (((([Content_Accuracy_q].[MinOfResolvedDate]) Between #9/1/2018# And (DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0))) In 
    (SELECT TOP 10 Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST

    FROM Content_Accuracy_q

    Where ((Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 3 - Issue ST])="Inaccurate Information" Or (Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 3 - Issue ST])="Change of accommodation") AND ((Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 4 - Reason ST])<>"Cost"))))
    GROUP BY "FY" & IIf(Month([MinOfResolvedDate])<10,Year([MinOfResolvedDate]),Year([MinOfResolvedDate])+1), "Resolved", Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy"), Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm"), Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST

    HAVING (((Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST)<>""))

    ORDER BY Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC , Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC)

ORDER BY Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC , Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC;
```

However, I continuously get the 'Syntax error in ORDER BY clause' and can't get past this point. Has anyone been able to successfully run a query similar to this and return the top 'X' results by count within the months needed?

Comment: "mysql" is not "ms access". They are two totally different products. People following the MySQL tag are probably not that interested in a question about Access (unless they happen to have expertise in both). Please read the tag definitions before you use them, thanks :-). Please also provide some sample data and expected result to make it easier for people to understand your data structure and the context.

Answer (score 0):

On formatting your SQL with indentation, there are a few oddities in your code:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Financial Year] & "Resolved" & [Text Month] & [SegmentDescriptionST] AS [Key], 
    "FY" & IIf(Month([MinOfResolvedDate])<10,Year([MinOfResolvedDate]),Year([MinOfResolvedDate])+1) AS [Financial Year], 
    "Resolved" AS Metric, 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") AS [Resolved Month], 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm") AS [Text Month], 
    Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST, 
    Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) AS Amount
FROM 
    Content_Accuracy_q
WHERE 
    (
        (
            (
                [Content_Accuracy_q].[MinOfResolvedDate] BETWEEN #9/1/2018# AND DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
            )
            IN 
            (
                SELECT TOP 10 Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST
                FROM Content_Accuracy_q
                WHERE 
                (
                    Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 3 - Issue ST] = "Inaccurate Information" OR 
                    Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 3 - Issue ST] = "Change of accommodation"
                )
                AND 
                Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 4 - Reason ST] <> "Cost"
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY 
    "FY" & IIf(Month([MinOfResolvedDate])<10,Year([MinOfResolvedDate]),Year([MinOfResolvedDate])+1), 
    "Resolved", 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy"), 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm"), 
    Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST
HAVING 
    Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST <> ""
ORDER BY 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC, 
    Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC)
ORDER BY 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC,
    Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC;
```

First, the obvious error is that you have an unbalanced parenthesis in your first `order by` clause:

```sql
ORDER BY 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC, 
    Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC)
                                                       ^------- here
```

But then you also have two `order by` clauses, which is invalid syntax:

```sql
ORDER BY 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC, 
    Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC)
ORDER BY 
    Format([MinOfResolvedDate],"mmm-yy") DESC, 
    Count(Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST) DESC;
```

The `having` clause also seems redundant, as the criteria is not referencing a field which is the result of the aggregation:

```sql
HAVING 
    Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST <> ""
```

As such, this criteria could instead be included as part of the `where` clause:

```sql
FROM 
    Content_Accuracy_q
WHERE 
    Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST <> "" AND
```

However, looking at your `where` clause, this statement doesn't make sense to me:

```sql
(
    [Content_Accuracy_q].[MinOfResolvedDate] BETWEEN #9/1/2018# AND DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
)
IN 
(
    SELECT TOP 10 Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST
    FROM Content_Accuracy_q
    WHERE 
    (
        Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 3 - Issue ST] = "Inaccurate Information" OR 
        Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 3 - Issue ST] = "Change of accommodation"
    )
    AND 
    Content_Accuracy_q.[Level 4 - Reason ST] <> "Cost"
)
```

Here, the code is saying:

*"Select records where the result of `[Content_Accuracy_q].[MinOfResolvedDate] BETWEEN #9/1/2018# AND DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)` is one of the results returned by `SELECT TOP 10 Content_Accuracy_q.SegmentDescriptionST ...`"*

But the expression:

```sql
[Content_Accuracy_q].[MinOfResolvedDate] BETWEEN #9/1/2018# AND DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
```

Will return a boolean value (i.e. `True/False` `-1/0`); and I'm guessing that it is not your intention to check whether a boolean value is a member of the results returned by the subquery.